# Annihilators of Modules

Tags: commutative-algebra

I'm stuck trying to prove that for two $R$-modules $M,N$ ($R$ commutative with a 1), then $$Ann(M+N)=Ann(M) \cap Ann (N)$$

I was trying to do double inclusion, and I can prove the RHS is contained in the LHS, but im stuck in the other direction since if I take $x \in Ann(M+N)$, then for any $m,n \in M,N$ (resp.) $x(m+n)=0$, but I dont see why this means $xm=0=xn$.

So I was wondering if I could get some hints on how to prove this

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint without words:

$$x\in\text{Ann}(M+N)\implies x(m+n)=0\;,\;\;\forall\,m\in M\,,\,n\in N\implies$$

$$\implies x(m+0)=x(0+n)=0\;,\;\;\forall\,m\in M\,,\,n\in N\;\;\ldots$$

Comment: Of course!! I cant believe I didn't see that. Thank you

Comment: Any time, @Chris...